# Xcode- EXC_BAD_ACCESS During Coded Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, segue

In my app, I am trying to program a segue in code when a specific condition is met. I call the segue using [self performSegueWithIdentifier:Sender]. This is called in an IBAction, which is called by pressing a UIButton. However, I get the EXC_BAD_EXCESS error message. The actual error message is attached to a different line of code, but I think it is still referring to the segue based on what happened when the segue was commented out. Through NSLogging, I do know that the IBAction is indeed being called by the button.

The method in which the Button is created:

```
- (void)gameOver {
[run invalidate];
[xViewTimer invalidate];
[gameTimer invalidate];

gameOverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
gameOverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 100);

scoreIs = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:f];
scoreIs.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentCenter;
scoreIs.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
scoreIs.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scoreIs.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];
[scoreIs setText:@"You Finished With A Score Of:"];

UILabel *showPoints = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 100)];
showPoints.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
showPoints.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
showPoints.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
showPoints.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
[showPoints setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", points]];

UIButton *playAgainButt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
playAgainButt.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-70, 200, 140, 50);
[playAgainButt setTitle:@"Play Again" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[playAgainButt addTarget:self action:@selector(newGame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *toMain = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
toMain.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-70, 280, 140, 50);
[toMain setTitle:@"Main Menus" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[toMain addTarget:self action:@selector(mainMenuSegue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

scoreIs.hidden = NO;

[gameOverView addSubview:toMain];
[gameOverView addSubview:playAgainButt];
[gameOverView addSubview:showPoints];
[gameOverView addSubview:scoreIs];
[self.view addSubview:gameOverView];

NSLog(@"Game Over");
}
```

Then the mainMenuSegue that is called:

```
- (IBAction)mainMenuSegue {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"menu" sender:self]; 
}
```

There is a modal segue in my storyboard with the identifier "menu."

The couple other posts on the subject I found were mainly answered with solutions pertaining to memory management. I am using ARC with IOS 5 so I do not think this is the issue. All help is very much appreciated, and I can post any other code which might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
- (IBAction)mainMenuSegue:(id)sender {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"menu" sender:sender];
}
```

I dont think `self` has the context you think it does

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I tried this and got the same response. Any other ideas perhaps?

Comment: I added some more code. Could the problem be the segue itself in the storyboard? It is a modal segue between one view controller to another. Does it have to be to some sort of object to another view controller? I got the error: Receiver (<Classic_Gameplay_VC: 0xb58f860>) has no segue with identifier 'menu''. But i know that there is a segue, which leads me to believe its somehow the wrong type of segue.

Comment: Okay I solved it. I found a call to one of my selectors in the viewWillDissapear method. I was unaware that i had this- must've accidentally put it in. Thanks very much.

Comment: Please post it as an answer and mark as correct to not get other answers on already solved issue.